# Why can't I get this typescript plugin to work?

Tags: typescript

I'm working on these plugin example

https://github.com/MCKRUZ/TS-Plugin-HW

Essentially the issue that I'm having is that I can't get the module loader to recognize that the plug-in has additional functionality to the original.  I think I'm almost there but I need a little push.

I have a main file called Communicator.ts

```
    import * as communicatorModularAMD from "communicatorModularAMD";

    class Communicator {
        constructor() { }
        greet(message: string) {
            return communicatorModularAMD.goodbye();
        }
    };

    var communicator = new Communicator();

    document!.body.innerHTML = communicator.greet("Hello, world");
```

Very simple.  So CommunicatorModularAMD is a Javascript lib that I created and put into this little app.  I want to demonstrate creating a plug in for it so I wrote this

```
define(['CommunicatorModularAMD'], function() {
    return {
        goodbye: function() {
            return "<h1>Goodbye!</h1>";
        }
    };
});
```

With this declaration file

```
import * as m from 'communicatorModularAMD';

/*~ Here, declare the same module as the one you imported above */
declare module 'communicatorModularAMD' {
    /*~ Inside, add new function, classes, or variables. You can use
     *~ unexported types from the original module if needed. */
    export function goodbye(): string;


}
```

The Typescript compiles but when i go to run it, it wont find goodbye.

This is what I get back in the console.log for the communicatorModularAMD object, which does NOT contain goodbye.

```
{default: {…}, greet: ƒ}
greet: ƒ (message)
default: {greet: ƒ}
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Your factory returns `return communicatorPlugin;` but `goodbye()` is not defined on it. only `extendcommuincatorModularAMD` method exists on it

Comment: I updated it with new code....still doesn't work.

Comment: if you `console.log(communicatorModularAMD)` in your Communicator.ts file what do you get back?

Comment: I posted what I get back in the original post...no goodbye.

Comment: interesting. where is the `greet` coming from in your console.log of the imported module? your communicatorModularADM only returns a `goodbye`

Comment: it's coming from the original module, if you look at the code in github you can see.

Comment: you communicatorPlugin code is not imported into the bundle and thus does not execute. the .ts type definition is loaded and extended but as far as your .js code, it is not present in your bundle.js

Comment: @teddybeard correct.  That is really the issue.  How do I get it to get included into the bundle?  I tried to put it into "entry" but that didn't include it as a module.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210254/discussion-between-teddybeard-and-matt).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you cannot set any top level properties on an imported module, but you can set nested properties: `module.plugin.custom`

`app/Communicator.ts`

```
import * as communicatorModularAMD from "communicatorModularAMD";
import * as communicatorPlugin from "../communicatorPlugin";

console.log(communicatorPlugin);
console.log(communicatorModularAMD);

class Communicator {
    constructor() { }
    greet(message: string) {
        return communicatorModularAMD.plugin.goodbye();
    }
};

var communicator = new Communicator();

document!.body.innerHTML = communicator.greet("Hello, world");
```

`communicatorModularAMD/CommunicatorModularAMD.js`

```
define([], function () {
    return {
        plugin: {},
        greet: function (message) {
            return "<h1>" + message + "</h1>";
        }
    };
});
```

`communicatorModularAMD/index.d.ts`

```
declare module communicatorModularAMD {
    interface pluginList { }
    export var plugin: pluginList;
    export function greet(message: string): string;
}
```

`communicatorPlugin/index.js`

```
import 'communicatorModularAMD';

declare module 'communicatorModularAMD' {
    interface pluginList {
        goodbye(): string;
    }
}
```

`communicatorPlugin/index.d.ts`

```
define(['communicatorModularAMD'], function (communicatorModularAMD) {
    communicatorModularAMD.plugin.goodbye = function () {
        return "<h1>Goodbye!</h1>";
    }
    return communicatorModularAMD;
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do is possible. You can fool typescript into compiling by appending an extra `goodbye` method onto the interface of communicatorModularAMD but I don't think you can take an imported module and modify it. Typescript is simply for type checking at compile time and all Typescript code is deleted immediately after type checking is finished. Typescript cannot alter the functionality of your code. Do you have a tutorial or documentation of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: hey teddy, all I'm really trying to do is to create a plug in for an existing library.  Doesn't have to be a library I have wrote, just ANY library.  So for example if I created a plug-in for moment.js  There are some examples but none with declaration files

Comment: Also I tried the above, module loader still doesn't pull in the module.

Comment: what do you mean by plugin? you mention adding a plugin to lodash. does that mean you want to define a new method on lodash like lodash.pluginName() ?

Comment: the code above might pull in the module but maybe it's not working like you intended. try adding a console.log('loading plugin') to the plugin code and see if it is executed

Comment: In response to your plug in question, yes something like lodash.pluginname.

Comment: In response to your lather comment it’s not pulling it in at all b/c I don’t see the JavaScript file in the bundle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210265/discussion-between-teddybeard-and-matt).